# Configure log level server-wise in Grails

Tags: logging, grails

Is there a way to configure the log level of your application on the server?

One idea is: Grails 3 provides `grails.config.locations` in the "application.yml". So it would be great to have something like `grails.logback.locations`.

I was trying to set the log level in the "application.yml" and access the value from "logback.groovy", but this does not do because the `grails.util.Holders.getGrailsApplication()` is not yet started when running the logback.

Comment: `logback.groovy` and `application.yml` are both configuration files.  Is there some reason that you want to define your logging config values in `application.yml` and use them in `logback.groovy`, as opposed to defining them in `logback.groovy`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, the idea is that application.yml can be server-specific, using `grails.config.locations` whereas logback.groovy can not - can it??

Comment: You can have server specific logback config files if you like.  You can set the `logback.configurationFile` system property to point to your logback config.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Setting logback by a system property would affect the whole application server, right? Well, this would do for me by now, as only 1 of 3 running apps is using a logback file. An app-specific solution would be more favourable. Anyway, please feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: "Setting logback by a system property would affect the whole application server, right?" - You can set system properties at the application level.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown All I've found so far is setting server-wide system properties by modifying `bin/setenv.sh` (e. g. for Tomcat 9). If you could link an application-wide setting and write this whole thing into an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: How to set app specific system properties in your servlet container is a separate question than the one posted above.  You should post that as a new question (a Google search will quickly shed some light as well).  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure the log level of your application on the
> server?

There is.

One way to do that is to set the `logback.configurationFile` JVM system property to point to wherever your logback config file is on the server.  The specifics of how you do that will depend on what servlet container you are using.